# GCP : Listing available projects failed: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443):

Tags: google-cloud-platform, timeout

When i try to load the project list in gcp on my terminal, i see this error:
gcloud projects --list gives this error:
I am using mac with m1 chip, please help.

Listing available projects failed: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe1280833c8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out'))

Comment: Have you run `gcloud info --run-diagnostics` to check for network issues?